# How to permute various icons in indicator-applet?

Tags: indicator

I'm using Gnome classic in ubuntu 12.04.

I can only move the indicator applet as a whole. As in, I cannot individually change the positions of the battery icon, bluetooth, network-manager, date and time, etc.

Is there an option to individually move each of these icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out if this may help you.
[ubuntu4beginners.blogspot.com/2011/06/re-arrange-appindicators-in-ubuntu.html](http://ubuntu4beginners.blogspot.com/2011/06/re-arrange-appindicators-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.